# scrollTop breaking in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I know this is an issue that has been referenced on here before but I've tried every solution I can find and i still cannot get scrollTop to work in Firefox. Works great in Chome. 
I have a scrolldown button that scrolls through sections on the page:

```
$(function() {
var $window = $(window);
$('.display').on('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('section').each(function() {
        var pos = $(this).offset().top;   
        if ($window.scrollTop() < pos) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: pos
            }, 1500);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Any chance of a demo?

Comment: sure thing--http://jsfiddle.net/d1tw743z/2/  pretty much the jist of what im trying to do. scrolls section by section until it gets to the bottom of the page and then the next click would send you to the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code:

```
$('.display').on('click', function(e){
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        $('section').each(function() {
            var pos = $(this).offset().top;   
            if ($window.scrollTop() < pos) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: pos
                }, 1500);
                return false;
            }
            else if(pos > ($(window).height() * 3)){
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
            return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

event wasn't defined. It works for me now.

Comment: thanks Tyr it looks like your solution works when i test it on its own. However my site is still having issues. Now it will at least work for the first click, but the 2nd click does nothing unless i first manually scroll. Again, just an issue in Firefox. I've put up a very stripped down version of my page so maybe you can check it out quick if you dont mind?  

http://www.defyordie.com/dl/

Comment: I think you should debug the section where you check pos vs. window.scrollTop().Use firebug or the native developer tools of firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Firebug isn't getting me very far. Anyone else have any ideas? When i pare it down in a fiddle it looks like it should work, its just not working in MY implementation. http://www.defyordie.com/dl/

Comment: ive tested on the most recent version for mac & PC - the click to scroll button works the first time and then doesn't work for another click.